# How to Position Image to the Negative Right Position and Prevent Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have long searched for the answer and found nothing similar to my problem.
I have 3 blocks with `height: 200px; width: 500px;`. In second block I have image, that have negative right position, and with greater `height` than his container. And I do not want to see horizontal scrollbar before browser window < my container width. I want to "cut" image on right side if it does not fit in window. 
How can I do that?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g2LyLetn/)

```css
.container,
.container1,
.container2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.container1 {
  background: blue;
}
.container2 {
  background: green;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container2"></div>
```

Comment: You should have searched for the answer (not the search)

Comment: I think you want to use `overflow: hidden;` btw, to remove the scroll. (or `overflow-x: hidden;`)

Comment: Arg0n overflow-x causes vertical scroll. Try in fiddle yourself

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your parent container (in your case this is body) has `overflow-x:hidden` property. So you need to add

```
body {overflow-x:hidden; max-width: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/g2LyLetn/2/

you mean that way ?

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: No. This way I cant scroll anyway.